# Unable to change the case of a letter in Zsh

Tags: case, zsh

The code in my Zsh

```
#!/bin/zsh
q=$1

open "http://mathworld.wolfram.com/$q.html"
```

I put the input to the app

```
triangle
```

I get an error at Wolfram, since the first letter must be a big one.

**How can you change the case for the first letter in the variable q?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# q=triangle
# echo ${(C)q}
Triangle
```

See [Parameter Expansion Flags](http://chronos.cs.msu.su/zsh-man/zsh_15.html#SEC47).